# Was pietism an influence upon Kant's moral thoughts?

Tags: ethics, kant, history-of-philosophy

Pietism was a 17th century Lutheran theological movement emphasizing private religious study and kindness. Now, Kant was raised in a pietist household and enrolled in pietist schools. So is there any parallel between his moral philosophy and pietist teachings?

Comment: Some refernces: [Kant's Philosophy of Religion](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant-religion/) and R.JSullivan, [Immanuel Kant's Moral Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=rLFeQTQPPboC&pg=PA6).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

▻ PIETISTIC INFLUENCE IN GENERAL TERMS

> It is useful finally to remember that Kant grew up in the pietistic-eclectic,
>    anti-Wolff ian milieu of Koenigsberg.41 The emphasis on free will, on the
>    role of conscience, and the general moral pessimism which characterize
>    pietism furnished the basis upon which the rational-demonstrative meth
>    ods of dogmatic philosophy were criticized. The idea of a duty to believe in
>    what, he insisted, cannot and should not be proved, was the basis of the
>    moral philosophy of Crusius, whose influence on Kant in this connection
>    has yet to be adequately explored.42 For a proof cannot substitute for the
>    inner discipline of the subject, his recognition of an authority higher than
>    himself which morality requires. But this conviction poses a problem of
>    philosophical communication. How do you employ methods which are
>    rational but non-demonstrative to persuade your reader, not that he lives
>    in a world regulated by Providence, or indeed that any other proposition
>    is the case, but to submit himself to this moral discipline? Clearly this
>    cannot be done directly, for any such effort only leads to circularity from
>    the standard, demonstrative point of view. Kant cannot prove that the form
>    of morality is deontological rather than based in clannishness and sympa
>    thy, unless he can prove that God exists, while, according to the surface
>   scheme of his presentation, he cannot prove that God exists unless morality
>    really does take this form. (Catherine Wilson, 'Interaction with the Reader in Kant's Transcendental Theory of Method', History of Philosophy Quarterly, Vol. 10, No. 1 (Jan., 1993), 83-97 : 93-4.

▻ FINESSING THE PIETISTIC INFLUENCE

To descend a level of detail, you might find the following article of use :

Dennis Vanden Auweele, 'The Lutheran influence on Kant's depraved will',  International Journal for Philosophy of Religion, Vol. 73, No. 2 (April 2013), 117-135.

Here is an extract from the article, which makes relevant discriminations within pietism.

> Kant was actually raised in Pietism, not Lutheranism or Calvinism. Pietism is a theological movement within Lutheranism which is usually, in the constructivist understanding (cf. Wallmann (1990), taken to be initiated by Philipp Jakob Spener (1635-1705) and continued by August Hermann Francke (1663-1727). Several scholars (cf. Lindberg (2005) point towards the earlier influence of Johann Arndt (1555-1621), Johannes Tauler (1300-1361) and Thomas à Kempis (1380-1471) on the movement. Within Pietism, two sub-movements emerged: Moravianism and Halle Pietism, of which the latter influenced Kant the most. (Auweele, 118 footnote 3.)